# How to compile Qt app with specify version dependency

Tags: linux, qt, deployment, dependencies

I’m not sure how to describe it correctly, but I have a following problem.

I need to compile my Qt application with exactly dependency to specific Qt version. Currently when I compile my app on linux and try

```
ldd Application
```

I’m getting following result

```
...
libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/local/Trolltech/...
...
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
libQtCore.so.4.8.2 => /usr/local/Trolltech/...
```

The reason for this requirement is a deployment of my app. I would like to distribute my App together with default Qt libraries in one directory. I already updated rpath to APP/libs directory and everything works fine, until I tried to distribute my app to system with newer version of Qt.

In such cases I’m getting a following error:

```
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library .....
```

Comment: How do you compiling your Application? You can pass custom library path to your gcc compiler at compile time. -L<new_lib_path>

Comment: You get this by passing the -static option to gcc or to the linker. also you can use LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: I'm already passing -L param to linker by using qmake macro QMAKE_LIBDIR. But I didn't found a way how to specify exact file (for example libQtCore.so.4.8.2)

Comment: what about LD_LIBRARY_PATH using at runtime?

Comment: Don't know why but LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't working. Although I have correctly set-up path to single directory where I have all required files, my app still crashing with error about library mishmash.

Comment: Did you try statically compile library?

Comment: Here is your answer http://jpnurmi.kapsi.fi/blog/2008/03/16/how-to-switch-qt-version-in-ubuntu/